# Should I use Concrete dissolver or Muratic acid to remove splatter?

Tags: concrete, cleaning, stain-removal

Concrete splattered all over the siding on my shed while I was mixing a batch for my patio.  I have done a light google search and seen there is muriatic acid and some kind of concrete dissolvers. What is the best procedure to do this?

[muriatic acid](http://www.naturalhandyman.com/iip/infxtra/infmur.html)

[concrete dissolver](http://www.concrete-dissolver.com)

Answer (score 1):

I used muriatic acid to clean boats and to clear urinal drains.  I have seen it used to clean a cement mixer on youtube.  It is very strong stuff.  You just spray it on for a few minutes and then scrub with a brush or sponge.  Wear gloves and eye protection.  There are a few videos on youtube.

Comment: You will not like it at all if you inhale the vapors. Be careful about that.